# Why is the browser downloading images generated from client-side templates multiple times?

Tags: .net, http, caching, browser

i'm building a web app using [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org) and am using my own custom classes with Nancy to provide static content to the browser.

When i run a demo ([code here](https://github.com/jugglingnutcase/EmbeddedStaticIssue)), and click on a link that will remove an image from the page and then render that same image back using a client-side template, i see the browser make a request for the image after every click.

Here's a picture of my network requests in Chrome devtools after multiple clicks on my link that renders a template with an image:

[image: Network tools information from my broken app]

i expect that the image would not be downloaded from the server again. i only see one request for the image when i run this simple web app using the default Nancy application or something that isn't .NET-y. i've tried a Nancy's standard static content providers, a [golang file server](https://github.com/jugglingnutcase/goserve), [http-server](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server), [isaacs st](https://github.com/isaacs/st). They all behave like this:

[image: Network tools from golang standard file server]

i think i have my expiration or cache-related headers messed up, but i'm not sure. The headers ([here's the diff between the headers from the default Nancy implementation and my code as a gist](https://gist.github.com/jugglingnutcase/b35c3ee15b650bb5291b)) don't reveal anything that i'm picking up on.

i have many questions:

1. What's happening in the browser that causes images to be downloaded again?
2. How can i improve at using my devtools to figure out what's causing the image to be downloaded again by the browser?
3. If you feel like getting into it, what's wrong with my custom implementation?

i'm currently seeing this behavior in Chrome Version 33.0.1750.146 m on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cache busting? Appending a unique string (such as a GUID) to the URL will usually do the trick. Ex: /Content/face.png?v=7c1f4f57f2aa4cf9b707664fb0bd7a05

Edit: a typo

Comment: Hey! i didn't try cache busting, but i *don't want the image downloaded again*. i just think it should be downloaded once. i edited my question to clarify what i'm looking for (i don't think i was very clear originally)

Comment: When you create a new img element in the DOM, like the Hogan template is doing, the browser won't care that it rendered it before, it's going to treat it agnostically. Static content caching (like images) has to be controlled from the server, not from within the app.

Comment: i agree, i do think there's an issue with my implementation of static content caching, but i'm not sure what. My requests/responses don't look very different from other implementations that i see.

Comment: When i use other static servers (ie go's default, or nodeapps/http-server) i don't see the image downloaded each time, just once. Why doesn't mine behave that way?